# Solve this Dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that the Dirichlet problem

$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} u_{xx}+ u_{yy}=u^3 \ \text{in} \ x^2+y^2 \lt 1 \\ u=0 \ \text{on} \ x^2+y^2 = 1 \end{array} \right.$$

where $u=u(x,y)$, has only the trivial solution $u \equiv 0$

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Can you share what you've tried, and what's giving you trouble? Although people are happy to help with homework and similar questions, your question will probably not get much attention unless you show your efforts.

Comment: Hint: Use the maximum principle.

Comment: If u is constant, then u has to be identically equal to zero. Now I suppose that u is not constant. I think we can only the maximum principle when $\Delta$ u is $\ge 0$. But here we don't know this@Riemann1337

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion@T.Bongers

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$\Delta u=u^3\mbox{ on }D$$
where $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2< 1\}$. Multipying $u$ on both sides and integrating it over $D$, we get
$$\tag{1}\int_Du\Delta u=\int_D u^4\geq 0.$$
By Stokes' Theorem, we have 
$$\tag{2}\int_Du\Delta u=-\int_D|\nabla u|^2+\int_{\partial D}u\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}
=-\int_D|\nabla u|^2$$
where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$ is the normal derivative of $u$ on $\partial D$, and the last equality follows from the boundary condition that $u=0$ on $\partial D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2= 1\}$.  Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain 
$$\int_D|\nabla u|^2\leq 0$$
which implies that $\nabla u\equiv 0$ in $D$, or equivalently, $u$ is a constant in $D$. Since $u=0$ on $\partial D$, we must have $u=0$ in $D$.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different take on it:

Let $u(x, y)$ be a solution to

$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = u^3 \tag{1}$

in the open unit disk $B(0, 1) = \{ (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 < 1 \}$, with

$u(x, y) = 0 \tag{2}$

on $\partial B(0, 1) = \{ (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}$.  Without going into further details of the analysis, I am going to assume $u(x, y) \in C^2(\bar B(0, 1), \Bbb R)$, where $\bar B(0, 1) = \{(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$;  note that $\bar B(0, 1) = B(0, 1) \cup \partial B(0, 0)$.  Then $u(x, y)$, being a continuous, real-valued function on the compact set $\bar B(0, 1)$, actually takes on its maximum and minimum values at some points in $\bar B(0, 1)$; let $M$ be the maximum, and $m$ be the minimum, values of $u(x, y)$ on the set $\bar B(0, 1)$so that
$m \le u(x, y) \le M$ for $(x, y) \in \bar B(0, 1)$.  Then we have

$m \le 0 \le M. \tag{3}$

(3) follows from the boundary conditions imposed upon $u(x, y)$:  if we had $M < 0$, then $u(x, y) \le M < 0$ on $\bar B(0, 1)$, contradicting (2); a similar argument shows $m \le 0$.  Now if $m = M = 0$, then $u(x, y) = 0$ and there is nothing left to prove; so we can assume at least one of $m, M \ne 0$.  If $M > 0$, there must be a point $P_M \in B(0, 1)$ with $u(P_M) = M > 0$; $P_M \notin \partial B(0, 1)$ since $u(x, y) = 0$ for $(x, y) \in \partial B(0, 1)$.  We have

$\nabla u(P_M) = 0, \tag{4}$

since $P_M$ is a local (at least) maximum of the function $u(x, y)$.  Furthermore, at $P_M$, (1) becomes

$u_{xx}(P_M) + u_{yy}(P_M) = u^3(P_M) = M^3 > 0. \tag{5}$

Next, we examine the Hessian, or matrix of second derivatives, of $u$ at $P_M$:

$Hess(u)(P_M) = \begin{bmatrix} u_{xx}(P_M) & u_{xy}(P_M) \\ u_{yx}(P_M) & u_{yy}(P_M) \end{bmatrix}; \tag{6}$

we see from (5) that the trace of $Hess(u)(P_M)$ is

$\text{Tr}(Hess (u)(P_M)) = u_{xx}(P_M) + u_{yy}(P_M) = M^3 > 0, \tag{7}$

which implies that *at least one eigenvalue of the symmetric matrix $Hess(u)(P_M)$ is positive*!  Let $\lambda$ be such a positive eigenvalue of $Hess(u)(P_M)$, and let $\mathbf e$ be the corresponding unit eigenvector; we know such $\lambda, \mathbf e$ exist since $Hess(u)(P_M)$ is symmetric.  Then

$Hess(u)(P_M) \mathbf e = \lambda \mathbf e, \tag{8}$

and we can compute the first and second derivatives of $u(x, y)$ along the line $P_M + t \mathbf e$ at the point $P_M$ where $t = 0$ as follows:

$(du(P_M + t \mathbf e) / dt)_{t = 0} =  \nabla u(P_M) \cdot \mathbf e = 0 \tag{9}$

by (4);

$(d^2u(P_M + t \mathbf e) / dt^2)_{t = 0} = \mathbf e \cdot Hess(u)(P_M) \mathbf e = \mathbf e \cdot \lambda \mathbf e = \lambda > 0. \tag{10}$

Equation (9) is well-known and (10) follows from the formula

$du(P_M + t \mathbf e) / dt =  \nabla u(P_M + t\mathbf e) \cdot \mathbf e \tag{11}$

by performing a second differentiation with respect to $t$, using the chain rule, and finally evaluating at $t = 0$.  The details are easy to execute.  Taken together, (9) and (10) show that, for sufficiently small $t$, $u(x, y)$ is in fact *increasing* along the line $P_M + t \mathbf e$, so that for such small $t \ne 0$ $u(P_M + t\mathbf e) > u(P_M)$, which contradicts the assumption that $u(x, y)$ takes on its maximum value $M > 0$ at $P_M$.  A corresponding, similar argument disposes of the case $m < 0$; then we have $\text{Tr}(Hess (u)(P_m)) = m^3 < 0$ so that one of the eigenvalues $\lambda < 0$ and so forth.  In any event, these deliberations indicate that the only way to avoid a contradiction is to assume $m = M = 0$, in which case $u(x, y) = 0$ on 
$\bar B(0, 1)$ as we have seen.  QED.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***